# AIR AS3 file download is corrupted when bandwidth is low

Tags: actionscript-3, iis, download, air, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using a Downloader class to get large files from a IIS server on WS2012 and handle download progress.

It works fine, however when the client's bandwidth is too saturated, Progress events aren't fired anymore and after a certain amount of time the download just stops (the Complete event seems to be triggered?), despite the download being unfinished, leaving the client with a corrupt file.

I couldn't find out how to solve this, or even what strategy I should take on this problem (finish the download and display an error? Wait for bandwidth availability to get my next piece of bytes?)

Here's the Downloader.as class

```
public class Downloader extends EventDispatcher
{
    [Event(name="DownloadComplete", type="DownloadEvent")]

    public static var spd:int = 0;
    private var file:File;
    private var fileStream:FileStream;
    private var url:String;
    private var urlStream:URLStream;

    var mc_background:MovieClip;
    var howManyTimes:Number = 3; //How many times per second  the download speed will be traced
    var bytesLoaded:Number = 0; //don't change, necessary for calculation
    var lastTime:int = 0; //don't change, necessary for calculation


    private var waitingForDataToWrite:Boolean = false;

    public function Downloader(s:MovieClip)
    {
        mc_background = s;

        lastTime = getTimer();
        urlStream = new URLStream();

        urlStream.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, onOpenEvent);
        urlStream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressEvent); 
        urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteEvent);

        fileStream = new FileStream();
        fileStream.addEventListener(OutputProgressEvent.OUTPUT_PROGRESS, writeProgressHandler)

    }

    public function download(formUrl:String, toFile:File):void {
        this.url = formUrl;
        this.file = toFile;
        mc_background.pb.file_txt.text = file.name;
        fileStream.openAsync(file, FileMode.WRITE);
        urlStream.load(new URLRequest(url));
    }

    private function onOpenEvent(event:Event):void {
        waitingForDataToWrite = true;

        dispatchEvent(event.clone());
    }

    private function onProgressEvent(event:ProgressEvent):void {
        var time:int = getTimer();
        if(time - lastTime >= (1000/howManyTimes))
        {
            var kiloBytes:Number = (event.bytesLoaded - bytesLoaded)/1000;
            var timeInSecs:Number = (time - lastTime)/1000;

            var kbsPerSecVal:Number = Math.floor(kiloBytes/timeInSecs);
            trace(kbsPerSecVal + " kbs/s");

            mc_background.pb.speed_txt.text = kbsPerSecVal + " kbs/s";
            bytesLoaded = event.bytesLoaded;
            lastTime = getTimer();
        }
        if(waitingForDataToWrite){
            writeToDisk();
            dispatchEvent(event.clone());
        }
    }

    private function writeToDisk():void {
        var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        urlStream.readBytes(fileData, 0, urlStream.bytesAvailable);
        fileStream.writeBytes(fileData,0,fileData.length);
        waitingForDataToWrite = false;

        dispatchEvent(new DataEvent(DataEvent.DATA));
    }

    private function writeProgressHandler(evt:OutputProgressEvent):void{
        waitingForDataToWrite = true;
    }

    private function onCompleteEvent(event:Event):void {
        if(urlStream.bytesAvailable>0)
            writeToDisk();
        fileStream.close();

        fileStream.removeEventListener(OutputProgressEvent.OUTPUT_PROGRESS, writeProgressHandler);

        dispatchEvent(event.clone());
        // dispatch additional DownloadEvent
        dispatchEvent(new DownloadEvent(DownloadEvent.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE, url, file));
    }

}
```

Comment: I cant explain the behaviour only some suggestions to handle it.. `..finish the download and display an error? or wait for bandwidth availability to get my next piece of bytes?` Well why not do both? If there is a problem bring up notice saying **"A network error caused an incomplete download"** at this point show 2 buttons: "Resume download" or "Keep what I got".. If you want to resume you can read **[this](http://richapps.de/resumable-downloads-with-air/)** and **[this also](http://mariusht.com/blog/2010/03/10/resumable-file-downloader-simple-air-app/)**...

Comment: Resuming the download seems good to me. When the complete event is fired before the file finished downloading,  I could try resuming the download several times, and then stop if it fails for too long. I'd appreciate if someone could detail that in an answer.

Comment: Have an `int` variable that stores expected filesize.. When the Event Complete fires now check if your [download] `fileData.length` is equal to `expected_FileSize`.. If less then retry until equal or whatever is good enough. To get from last bytes amount you use a "range request" in the request header. It's also shown **[in this link](https://suzhiyam.wordpress.com/tag/range-header-in-as3/)** If that helps you. Something like `URLRequestHeader("range","bytes="+startPOS+"-"+endPOS);` where startPOS is `filedata.length+1` and endPos is `expected_FileSize` amount.

Comment: @VC.One It works. You should post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an int variable that stores expected filesize..

When the Event Complete fires now check if your [download] fileData.length is equal to expected_FileSize.

If less then retry until equal or whatever is good enough. To get from last bytes amount you use a "range request" in the request header. It's also shown in this link If that helps you.

Something like 
`URLRequestHeader("range","bytes="+startPOS+"-"+endPOS);` where startPOS is filedata.length+1 and endPos is expected_FileSize amount.